Can courts in the US freeze the finances of associated businesses like in Brazil?
In Brazil, a Supreme Court Justice recently ordered the freezing of finances for SpaceX's Starlink, an entity owned by Elon Musk, due to non-compliance by another Musk-owned business, X (formerly Twitter).
https://www.cnbc.com/2024/08/29/elon-musk-brazil-judge-x-ban-starlink-freeze.html
I wonder if the same thing can happen in US.

Under what circumstances could US courts freeze the finances of one business due to the actions of another associated business?
Are there any notable US cases where similar actions were taken?

I am looking for insights into the legal principles and precedents that govern such actions in the US.
EDIT: This question is different from a seemingly duplicate question.
What is the legal basis for Brazil freezing starlink assets due to twitter/x fines?
My question asks for answers in the context of U.S. I don't care about the legal basis for Brazil but concerned whether the same thing applies in U.S.
